# msal-node error trying to resolve endpoints

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have been using MSAL in my React app for some time with success. One of the tokens that my app requests is for scope 'https://management.core.windows.net/user_impersonation'. I have a nodeJS server that I want to push that token acquisition to so I installed msal-node (1.12.1) and tried using the OBO flow:

```
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
  auth: {
      clientId: settings.config.azure.clientId,
      clientSecret: settings.config.azure.clientSecret,
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>",
      knownAuthorities: ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>"],
  }
});

const request = {
    scopes: ['https://management.core.windows.net//user_impersonation'],
    oboAssertion: <token_extracted_from_auth_header>
}

const response = await pca.acquireTokenOnBehalfOf(request);
return response.accessToken;
```

However the above code results in the following error:

ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

If I visit the URL it complains about I do get back some metadata so not really sure why it is failing.

Anybody have a suggestion?

Also in regards to OBO flow:

- For my nodeJS app I have added that permission to the required API list
- I presume the oboAssertion field is the token that is passed to my nodeJS app by the client? I simply extracted it from the Auth header

Comment: After further investigation it seems that this error is masking another error from msal-node 1.9.1+ (for me at least). If I downgrade to 1.9.0 it all works as expected. For those interested my bug report is here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5139

Answer (score 3):

The actual error message there means that the URL that we are trying to contact is wrong. And it is wrong `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` returns an error.

A coorrect one is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/19d5f71f-6c9a-4e7f-b629-2b0c38f2b167/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Notice how I used an actual teanant_id there. You can get yours from the Azure Portal - it's the "directory id"

[image]

If your web api is single tenant, i.e. it is only meant for the people in 1 organization, then the  is the tenant id of that organization. It is also known as "directory id". You get it from the Azure Portal.

However, if your api is multi-tenant, i.e. it's a bit more complicated, and the "correct" answer is to use the tenant id of the incoming assertion. It's the `tid` claim in it.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the URL is a result of my crappy editing skills, It does in fact have my tenant in it. The actual issue it seems is to do with msal-node 1.9.1+ and my version of node (16). I raised a bug report for this because downgrading to msal-node 1.9.0 works fine. The underlying issue has nothing actually to do with the URL at all

Comment: Could you point me to the bug you raised? We can discuss there directly.

Comment: As per my bug https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5139 it was an issue with my project and I closed without further action

Answer (score 0):

Check 'authority' parameter of auth object.

authority: set to ***[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{DIRECTORY_ID}}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BDIRECTORY_ID%7D%7D)***, replacing the ***{{DIRECTORY_ID}}*** with the Azure AD directory ID of the Azure AD application

[take directory id from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y51rE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your .env file you must be **missing** some of the .env credentials like TENEANT ID, CLIENT ID, EndPoint, etc.